# Product of Elements in a list by using head, tail and null

Tags: haskell

So basically i am supposed to use head to take the first element and multiply and iterate through the list with tail and null. I am very new to haskell so i do not understand the flow control at all. The code below already works i just need to figure out where to use tail and iterate through the list.

```
module Blueprint where
import Prelude


x=1
prod :: [Integer] -> Integer
prod n 
|null n == True = 0
|null n== False = x*head n
```

adding some pseudo code:

```
x=1
prod :: [Integer] -> Integer
prod n 
|null n == True = 0
|null n== False = x*head n  do tail n repeat until null n == true
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Teaching to perform such a task using partial functions, when pattern matching would be safer and simpler, should be regarded as a criminal offense. ;-P

Comment: yeah well my professor thinks otherwise :D

Comment: I can actually understand professors giving these kinds of exercise: they want to make sure you understand `head,tail`,etc. Still, if I had to teach Haskell I would not mention them (if not at the very end) so to make sure pattern matching is well understood. I'd also postpone guards: lately on SO guards have seen much abuse. Even above the guards `null n == True` and `==False` should be avoided. (`x == True` is equivalent to `x`, and I'd use `otherwise` for the last case -- of course, with pattern matching there would be no guards around...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've almost got it! You just need to recursively call `prod` to get the product of the tail of the list, then multiply the head of the list by the result.

```
prod :: [Int] -> Int
prod xs
    | null xs = 1
    | otherwise = head xs * prod (tail xs)  -- note recursive call to prod
```

Incidentally, it's more idiomatic to use *pattern matching* to deconstruct your list, rather than manually calling `head`, `tail` and `null`.

```
prod [] = 1
prod (x:xs) = x * prod xs
```

Hopefully you can see how this is equivalent to the code above.

Terser still is expressing `prod` as a *fold*:

```
prod = foldr (*) 1
```

`foldr` is the standard Haskell idiom for consuming a list one element at a time. It's defined like this:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f acc [] = acc
foldr f acc (x:xs) = f x acc (foldr f acc xs)
```

Substitute `*` for `f` and `1` for `acc` in that definition and you'll recover `prod` from above.